# How can I clean source code files of invisible characters?

Tags: unicode, character

I have a bizarre problem: Somewhere in my HTML/PHP code there's a hidden, invisible character that I can't seem to get rid of. By copying it from Firebug and converting it I identified it as `&#xFEFF;` or 'Zero width no-break space'. It shows up as non-empty text node in my website and is causing a serious layout problem.

The problem is, I can't get rid of it. I can't see it in my files even when turning Invisibles on (duh). I can't seem to find it, no search tool seems to pick up on it. I rewrote my code around where it could be, but it seems to be somewhere deeper in one of the framework files.

How can I find characters by charcode across files or something like that? I'm open to different tools, but they have to work on Mac OS X.

Comment: vi or vim will show up any non-EOL characters.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [Textwrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/) will do it. EDIT: [VersionTracker link](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/18529) as Bare Bones site seems to be down again.

Comment: Don't blame yourself too much. If a layout breaks because of a zero-width, non-breaking space, the renderer is misunderstanding either the sero-width or the non-breaking part.

Comment: That's debatable I suppose. The non-breaking space connected two proper whitespace characters, so it's supposed to render something I guess. And that something happened to be squished inbetween two full-width, no-margin DIVs, which is why it showed up very prominently.  I rather blame Microsoft for inventing BOMs to begin with. ;-)

Comment: Cleaned up some simple answers and edited. Looks on-topic without an explicit tool request

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You don't get the character in the editor, because you can't find it in text editors. #FEFF or #FFFE are so-called [byte-order marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). They are a Microsoft invention to tell in a Unicode file, in which order multi-byte characters are stored.

To get rid of it, tell your editor to save the file either as ANSI/ISO-8859 or as Unicode **without BOM**. If your editor can't do so, you'll either have to switch editors (sadly) or use some kind of truncation tool like, e.g., a hex editor that allows you to see how the file **really** looks.

On googling, it seems, that TextWrangler has a "UTF-8, no BOM" mode. Otherwise, if you're comfortable with the terminal, you can use Vim:

```
:set nobomb
```

and save the file. Presto!

The characters are always the **very first** in a text file. Editors with support for the BOM will not, as I mentioned, show it to you at all.

Comment: I saw that before, but it usually rendered as garbage on top of the page. Seems it's harder to find when it's in the middle of a page...? Anyway, thanks! :)

Comment: It can occur in the middle of a page, when you use PHP's include statement with a BOM-started file to include. Otherwise it should usually not appear (although it _is_ a standard Unicode character and can be used as such).

Comment: If you're editing your HTML/PHP code with Altova XMLSpy then the option to turn off BOM is found at menu "Tools/Options", tabpage "Encoding". XMLSpy can preserve BOM if it finds it, or add it to a file when it doesn't exist yet. It has no option to remove BOM.

Comment: Oh, oops. I somehow doubt that you're using XMLSpy on a Mac OS X, although it can be installed on Mac OS X by using "Parallels for Mac" virtualization.

Comment: wowowow you just saved me such an insane amount of time. I actually cant even believe this. I was seeing &#xFEFF; being rendered as html but could not find this anywhere in the html files and was so confused. Thank you thank you thank you!!!

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Textmate and the problem is in a UTF-8 file:

1. Open the file
2. File > Re-open with encoding > ISO-8859-1 (Latin1)
3. You should be able to see and remove the first character in file
4. File > Save
5. File > Re-open with encoding > UTF8
6. File > Save

It works for me every time.

Answer (score 7):

It's a [byte-order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark). Under Mac OS X: open terminal window, go to your sources and type:

```
grep -rn $'\xFEFF' *
```

It will show you the line numbers and filenames containing BOM.

Comment: Since it almost certainly are the first two bytes of the file, the problem is to get it away. I'm not quite experienced with awk, but it should be a one-liner with it to remove the first two bytes of a file.

Comment: Indeed, it is not hard to find duplicate questions which show you how to do exactly that. `awk 'NR==1 { sub(/^\357\273\277/, "") } 1' file >newfile`

Answer (score 3):

In Notepad++, there is an option to show all characters. From the top menu:

View -> Show Symbol -> Show All Characters

Comment: As stated, I'm more looking for a Mac OS X (or UNIX) tool.

Comment: yep i missed that... i think i saw some where it can be run using Crossover. not pretty solution though

Comment: Btw: Notepad++ has an option to save Unicode files without BOM. Just in case you're gonna switch to Windows ;-)

Comment: i run notepad++ on ubuntu using wine. i don't know if wine runs on OS X. notepad++ is awesome though.

Comment: I don't think notepad plus plus will show 'no break space' and other whitespace characters, although it will show carriage returns and line feeds... I think you have to the switch encoding, which is explained in the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Mac user, but my general advice would be: when all else fails, use a **hex editor**. Very useful in such cases.

See ["Comparison of hex editors" in WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors).

Comment: Even among tool request question answers, this one is not particularly useful since it does not go so far as to suggest a solution or even a tool, only a category of tools.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little late to answer to this question, but I am adding how to change encoding in Visual Studio, hope it will be helpfull for someone who will be reading this sometime:

1. Go to File -> Save (your filename) as...
2. And in File Explorer window, select small arrow next to the Save button -> click Save with Encoding...
3. Click Yes (on *Do you want to replace existing file* dialog)
4. And finally select e.g. Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - that removes BOM