# What is the best way to catch extraneous output with PHP?

Tags: php

I am building a site and for the life of me can not tell how this character (shows Unicode symbol for invalid codepoint) is being prepended to *some* (articles) of my pages (before the doctype).

I have searched through the site's program flow and haven't found anything. There is only one `echo`, which echoes the request's response after sending headers.

I am using Kohana 3, but I don't think it is too relevant to what I am asking (I've worked with Kohana for years and never had this, I doubt it is framework related).

I have looked at all PHP files included in my `application/` folder, and they appear to be normal.

The `Request::instance()->execute()` is where the output is originating from in my `bootstrap.php` (wrapping the call with `echo`s proved this). The `articles.php` controller has no output, and either does the model or parent controller.

What methods can I use to find this output?

Comment: Can you post a URL giving you trouble?

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry, my Unicode codepoint block thing was munched when I posted.

Comment: A [BOM issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067742/clean-source-code-files-of-invisible-characters) perhaps?

Comment: @Brad Yes, [work in progress though](http://www.toberua.com/~new/your-residences/tropical-ocean-front-bure)... :)

Comment: It sounds like heaps of breakpoints are the best bet to isolate the source.

Comment: @deceze It just may be, unfortunately I have no experience with this happening to me. Guess that is about to change :)

Comment: The character in question is a single byte, and is `0x0E`.

Comment: @Brad Thanks, is that helpful to you in any way?

Comment: @alex, yeah, I was pointing it out for others so they didn't assume a BOM issue.  But, it looks like you found it.

Answer (score 2):

I turned on *Show Invisible Characters* in my IDE (Coda) and saw this lovely, eh, red *thing*.

[image: Coda]

I used trusty backspace, and now it is gone! :D

I have no idea how it got there...

Comment: Ha, I'll hand it to you, nice find :P

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that might be the pesky byte-order mark (as deceze says in his comment). Try saving your PHP scripts as UTF-8 without BOM and see if it helps. If you are seeing the unknown-code-point symbol that could have something to do with your pages being served as ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 as well.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock. I am specifying the charset as UTF-8 in the headers, so it should be good for UTF-8. I'll look into saving the files without BOM (though I am still unsure *which* file is being the pest).

Comment: I'm using Coda, and looks like I can save only as UTF-8 (no option for BOM).

Comment: @alex: OK I checked, Coda 1.7 saves without the BOM so that's the right way to go. I verified this by making a new PHP file, saving it, connecting to my Mac from my PC and opening the file with Notepad++ which differentiates between UTF-8 with and without the BOM.

Comment: @alex: It should be the same for 1.6.

Comment: @BoltClock So it's not a BOM issue?

Comment: It isn't a BOM... the character is only one byte.