# When compiling a Yguard Ant target in IntelliJ, there is an Error: The <yguard> type doesn't support nested text data ("")

Tags: intellij-idea, obfuscation, yguard

When compiling a Yguard Ant target in IntelliJ, there is an Error: "The <yguard> type doesn't support nested text data ("")". Any help on fixing the cause of this error would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the YGuard Ant Target:

```
<target  name="yguard">
        <taskdef name="yguard" classname="com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask" classpath="yguard.jar"/>
        <yguard>
            <inoutpair in="/Users/user/IdeaProjects/java.jar" out="/Users/user/IdeaProjects/java_obf.jar"/>
        </yguard>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be to change the encoding, to remove invisible characters that aren't being processed by the IDE, that come from copying and pasting. I pasted the code into komodo editor, changed the encoding to ISO-8859-1, then pasted it back into the build.xml and the error went away.

There are is also more information on correcting this error:

[Convert DOS line endings to Linux line endings in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726/convert-dos-line-endings-to-linux-line-endings-in-vim/82743#82743)

[Clean source code files of invisible characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067742/clean-source-code-files-of-invisible-characters)

https://superuser.com/questions/560014/vim-remove-bad-hidden-characters