# PHP login form not working after uploading the website

Tags: php, mysql, session, web-hosting

EDIT: There are invisible spaces after the PHP tag. I removed them, and it's now working.

So I have this website project that was built for 4 weeks.
[THE LOGIN FORM HERE IS WORKING.](http://www.meteachers.com)

This is the code for the login.php

```
<?php
 session_start(); // Starting Session
 $error=''; 

 if (isset($_POST['ComeIn'])) { //NAME OF THE BUTTON CLIKED

if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['pwd'])) {   //IF EMPTY
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else 
    {

        $username=$_POST['email'];
        $password=$_POST['pwd'];
        include ('connection.php');


        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);


        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from user_account where Password='$password' AND Email='$username'", $connection);
        $row1= mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

            if ($rows == 1) {   //IF OK
                if ($row1['AccType'] == "Teacher")
                {
                    $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
                    header("location: teachers/teacherprofile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
                }
                else if ($row1['AccType'] == "Student")
                {
                    $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
                    header("location: students/studentprofile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
                }

                else
                {
                    echo ("<script language = 'Javascript'>
                            window.alert('Incorrect Input!')
                            window.location.href='index.php'
                            </script>");
                }
            } else 
                {
                    echo ("<script language = 'Javascript'>
                            window.alert('Incorrect Input!')
                            window.location.href='index.php'
                            </script>");
                }
                }

        mysql_close($connection); 
    }

?>
```

But this [admin login form](http://www.meteachers.com/login_csa.php) is not working and it has almost the same code. It's not going anywhere. It's just going to login2.php and none of the PHP functions are working. Below is the login2.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; 
include ('connection.php');



if (isset($_POST['login'])) { //NAME OF THE BUTTON CLIKED

    if (empty($_POST['aemail']) || empty($_POST['apwd'])) { //IF EMPTY
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }
    else //TEXTFIELDS NOT EMPTY
        {

            $username=$_POST['aemail'];
            $password=$_POST['apwd'];
            include ('connection.php');


            $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
            $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);


            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from service_account where CS_Password='$password' AND CS_Email='$username'", $connection);
            $row1= mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);



                if ($rows == 1) {   //IF OK
                    if ($row1['SA_Type'] == "Admin")
                    {
                        $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
                        header("location: admin/admin_dashboard.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
                    }
                    else if ($row1['SA_Type'] == "Customer Service")
                    {
                        $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
                        header("location: cservice/cs_inquiry.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
                        header("location: login_csa.php");
                    }
                } else 
                    {
                    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
                    header("location: login_csa.php");
                    }

            mysql_close($connection); 
        }
}

?>
```

Im debugging this for two days now. THe weird part is, When I tried to use the system in localhost, it's perfectly working. When I put it in iPage.com, that happens. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can get rid the `$connection` in your `mysql_query()`. and is there any error?

Comment: Your script is probably dying or not meeting any of the conditions. Put this `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script and show us what errors pop up.

Comment: the other thing is that `mysql_*` is deprecated.... check the php version that you are running right now...

Comment: when i put the ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1); I got this error: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /hermes/bosoraweb126/b1216/ipg.meteacherscom/login2.php:2) in /hermes/bosoraweb126/b1216/ipg.meteacherscom/login2.php on line 4

Comment: Side note, you should not be storing passwords in plaintext.

Comment: You probably have an invisible unicode character at the beginning of your script.

Comment: The first user login form is working, but the other one, even having almost the same code, is not working.

Comment: @Darren how would I kow if there is any?

Comment: @rodortega Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3085715/2518525) answer, and give it a shot!

Comment: @Darren It worked! There are invisible characters inside. I love you now (no homo).

Comment: @rodortega perfect, don't worry we've all been there man! I spent a week once trying to fix the same issue and it was because there were 2 spaces after my closing `?>`. Now that's messed up! Do you want me to put it as an answer so you can close your question?

Comment: Remove everything before the <?php tag, spaces, tabs, characters, html and new lines also.

Comment: @Darren unicode or ASCII ?

Comment: @Devashish just 2 spaces after, that's why you should never close your script off with `?>`, just leave it gone! (*it's counted as output, causing issues haha*)

Comment: @Darren hey darren, rod is not replying, but I request you to post the answer :)

Comment: @Devashish There you go, a reasonable explanation answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common occurrence and is called ["The White Screen of Death"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1475297/2518525).
You should turn on error reporting at the top of your script to figure out what the issue is, that's causing this!

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-`);
```

<sup>***Note:*** *This is almost always because output was sent to the browser before you tried to start a session or do something.*</sup>

The above will tell you exactly what the issue was, and in your case it did. Stating:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /hermes/bosoraweb126/b1216/ipg.meteacherscom/login2.php:2) in
>   /hermes/bosoraweb126/b1216/ipg.meteacherscom/login2.php on line 4

Now if you didn't have anything `echo`'ing to the screen before you started the session, then your issue **would** have to be some invisible characters within your PHP script.

If that's your case (*which it seems, was*), then you should follow this answer below to remove those invisible characters (***bad encoding***). Your script will run again properly.

- [Clean source code files of invisible characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3085715/2518525)

Comment: And I know where that name came from (the white screen of death) :)