# php require / require_once generates "&#xFEFF"

Tags: php, require, require-once

I require an extern php file, where just an echo is included, and it works well. The problem is, that the thing &#xFEFF is generated at the top. That produces a clean line in the top.
Do you know why?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067742/how-can-i-clean-source-code-files-of-invisible-characters should help with this issue

Answer (score 1):

Open your PHP file in Notepad and delete the code that will appear at the top of the page. Follow these steps: Choose "All file types", click once on the name of the file you want to correct and change the encoding to ANSI model and click the open button. After that, just resave the file.

Comment: The comment points to a duplicate question where there is an excellent answer.  Perhaps you can improve your answer by explaining why the steps are necessary.

Comment: the given answer did not solve my problem. so I decided to post how I solved it. However, I don't know the technical reason. I just found a way out.